# Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'. On iOS 17 and MacOS Sonoma

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, macos

I'm having this problem since I updated to the new version of MacOS Sonoma. I updated my version of XCode and updated my iPhone 14 Pro Max to the iOS 17 version.

When I launch the application from XCode it works correctly. The problem occurs when starting debugging from VS Code

```
Starting debug of 00008120-000C645E3EF3C01E (D74AP, iPhone 14 Pro Max, iphoneos, arm64e, 17.0.2, 21A351) a.k.a. 'iPhone de Keen' connected through USB...
[+2782 ms] 2023-09-29 22:00:27.863 ios-deploy[20812:444588] [ !! ] Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need
to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown!
[        ] Script started, output file is /dev/null
[        ] Script done, output file is /dev/null
[        ] ios-deploy exited with code 0
[        ] Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008120-000C645E3EF3C01E.
[        ] Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
[        ]   open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
[        ] Installing and launching... (completed in 5.7s)
[        ] Error launching application on iPhone de Keen.
[        ] "flutter run" took 21,806ms.
```

I have tried all flutter cleanup commands.

When I try to launch in the simulator there is no problem. I already tried cleaning the trusted certificates with the Macbook and I also have the latest version of Cocoapods.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
    es-MX)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at
      /Users/marcodiaz/Development/SDK/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (3 months ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/marcodiaz/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone de Keen (mobile)    • 00008120-000C645E3EF3C01E            • ios
      • iOS 17.0.2 21A351
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • A64939C3-DE0A-4AC7-ACC0-7F1241810420 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.132

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

[EDIT]
After searching for a solution for a while. I decided to download the latest version of Flutter. This apparently solved the problem.

Comment: Upgrade flutter. In [3.13.7](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel) it got fixed.